# Giving credit for help

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, ownership

How should I give credit for someone's help in writing my code when part of the code that I put together was written by someone else?

I want to give them credit for their work, but I do not know how I should cite the code that they contributed. I want to know how I can avoid plagiarism. What is the best way to cite the code that I did not make?

Comment: Where ? in your project ? In a question ? An answer ?

Comment: @kyle k: Someone's help in writing your code using Stack Overflow? Or someone's help in writing your code in general? In the latter case this question does not belong on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Make a note somewhere in the post with a proper citation.  There is no formal citation system required by SE; you are free to use whatever you feel is appropriate, or whatever is required by who you are citing (if appropriate).

In most cases, assuming the code is posted online (i.e. on a blog post, from documentation in a language, from another SO answer, etc.) a link is generally enough.

If the code is not available online then posting the company name, possibly the website, would be appropriate.

If it's from another SO user, even if it's not code posted online, posting a link to their profile would be appropriate.

If it's something else and you're not sure about how to cite a specific instance then you could post here on meta with the specifics of your situation and we'll be able to help you work out what a proper citation would be.

Answer (score 3):

Citations often include:

- The original author
- The location of the work, including:

  - Name of the source website
  - Name of the article cited
- A clearly-marked quotation

You may not need to use every piece every time. You should include all of the details needed to allow readers to understand where to find the original information.

**Example:**

As [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186381/servy) said in a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184017/giving-credit-for-help#answer-184018) on the Meta StackOverflow question "[giving credit for help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184017/giving-credit-for-help)"

> There is no formal citation system required by SE; you are free to use whatever you feel is appropriate, or whatever is required by who you are citing.

Simple links should be avoided because of link rot. If the location of the original information changes, your citation should include enough information to allow a reader to search and find it.

Comment: Thanks, i did not know if MLA or APA was appropriate in this case.